# VS Code regular expression white space including newlines?

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

Attempting to match white space including newlines followed by a brace, `{` or `}` then collapse the matching white space to a single space,  .

Matches `\s*([{}])` do not include the preceding newlines:

[image: VS Code match]

So, the replacement  `$1` does not collapse the newlines:

[image: VS Code replacement]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
[\s*\n*]*([{}])
```

`\n` for newline

Produces:

[image: VS Code collapses white space including newlines to a single space]

Comment: It should be `[\s\n]*([{}])`, since inside a character class `*` means itself.

Comment: Wondering, `\n` would not be [contained in `\s`...](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-classes-in-regular-expressions#whitespace-character-s) weird. Imho as soon as you take the `*` out of the class (like @InSync already suggested) it would match the same as OPs initial regex: `\s*([{}])`

Comment: IIRC VSCode treats `\s` as if `\n` weren't included if the regex doesn't itself include it. Also, the flavor VSCode uses is ECMAScript, since it is written in JS/TS + Electron and is therefore basically a website (as further evidence, `(?>)` is considered invalid).

Comment: @InSync I guess we both can't test it  I've never heard (so far) that there is any regex flavor that supports `\s` as a short for whitespace but would not include `\n` in it.

Comment: @bobblebubble I can: I'm actually running VSCode. For a file containing nothing but a space then multiple line breaks, `\s` only matches the space , but if I use `\n{0}\s`, everything matches. I know this because some time ago I read a comment by Wiktor Stribizhew about this exact problem (credit goes to him). I can't find anything in the docs about this, though.